# Obter valor de multiplos campos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Com faço em `each` de um formulário que contém `input` e `select`.
O post desse form é feito em json com ajax.

Meu script hoje pega os valores de 2 `input` assim:

```
var name = $('#news-nome').val(),
    email = $('#news-email').val();

sendData({email: email, nome: name})
```

Como eu faço para pegar o valor te todos campos sem precisar colocar um a um igual o exemplo acima? No caso do meu novo formulário são 17 campos se fosse seguir o exemplo acima seriam 17 variáveis.

Comment: Dá uma vista de olhos em: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/.

Comment: São todos do mesmo tipo ? você pode usar `$( "#minhaDiv" ).find( "input :text" )`

Comment: Sim, eu pego todos com a classe .input porem minha duvida é pegar o valor de cada e inserir em ordem no meu json que irei mandar.

Answer (score 0):

Como você respondeu ao [Lucas Queiroz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/37176/lucas-queiroz-ribeiro) que todos os campos são do mesmo tipo:

```
var json = {};

$( "#minhaDiv" ).find( "input :text" ) .each(function(){

  json[ $(this).attr('name') ] =  $(this).val();

})

console.log(json);
```

Talvez você tenha que implementar algumas verificações nesses valores, pois alguns podem estar `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Se os parâmetros de postagem estiverem declarados no atributo *name* do elemento de cada campo do seu formulário, você pode usar o método [`$.fn.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (comentado por @Zuul). O método irá retornar um texto de URL utilizável na propriedade **`"data"`** que fica dentro do objeto de opções do método `$.ajax` (`$.post`, etc).

Para entender melhor esse método, vamos supor que temos um formulário assim:

```html
<form>
    <select name="Tipo">
        <option>Caixa</option>
        <option selected>Leite</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Em seguida serializamos ele com [`$.fn.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```js
$("form").serialize()
```

e obtemos:

```js
"Tipo=Leite"
```

Se o caso for outro, você pode construir um objeto contendo cada parâmetro de postagem como propriedade, atribuindo o identificador do elemento de seu campo em sí. Com isso você pode percorrer cada propriedade e construir um novo objeto com os valores dos elementos.

*O identificador equivale ao valor que está declarado no atributo *id* de um elemento.

```
var dataBuffer = {
    "email": "news-email"
  , "nome": "news-nome"
};

var dataToPost = {};

for (var param in dataBuffer)
  dataToPost[param] = $('#'+dataBuffer[param]).val();

sendData(dataToPost);
```